# routing using $routeParams in angular

Tags: angularjs, service, routes

Hi friends I'm new into angular and want to develop a Single page application. For this I create a service to call data which is working fine and also create a controller for show user list. Facing problem when using routing. I want when user click on anyone tab from list page then user will land to detail page with detail of that user which was clicked in list page... Please check my code below

Getting this error in console with this code `userData.userslist(...).find is not a function`

**controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('assignment', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.service('userData', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    userslist : function(){
        return $http({'url' : 'js/data.json', 'method' : 'GET'}).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      }, function(data){
        console.log('some error')
      })
    }
  }
}]);


  myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'user-list.html',
            controller: 'users'
          }).
          when('/:username', {
            templateUrl: 'detail.html',
            controller: 'userdetail'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      });



myApp.controller('users', ['$scope', '$http', 'userData', function($scope, $http, userData){
  userData.userslist().then(function(data){
    $scope.items = [];


    angular.forEach(data.data.bst_users, function(item){
                   $scope.items.push(item);

               })

  })
}]);



/*>>>>>Problem is here<<<<<<*/

myApp.controller('userdetail', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'userData', function($scope, $routeParams, userData){
console.log($routeParams.username);

userData.find($routeParams.username, function(found){

    $scope.user = found;
})

console.log(scope.user)

}])


/*******Filters*******/

myApp.filter('removeSpace',function() {
    return function(input) {
        if (input) {
            return input.replace(/\s+/g, '-');    
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do  you get anything here : `console.log($routeParams.username);`?

Comment: yes I got user name in it which is correct

Comment: I want to know how to find username in service data.. ?

Comment: can you put userData.find function in above code

Comment: @vijay It doesn't exist, hence his issue.

Comment: `userData.userslist(...).find`  error says that there is no find function in userData service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service does not have any method `find()` that takes username as an input parameter. Currently, service returns a list as `userlist()`

Probably need to make an explicit call again to service to fetch the list of users and then filter it by username.

```
myApp.controller('userdetail', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'userData', function($scope, $routeParams, userData){

  console.log($routeParams.username);

  userData.userslist().then(function(data){
     $scope.items = [];
     angular.forEach(data.data.bst_users, function(item){
       $scope.items.push(item);

       //Find User here
       if(item.username == $routeParams.username) {
          $scope.user = item;
       };

     });
  });
}]);
```

Alternatively, when changing the route , you can store the `$scope.items` in [ng-cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) and fetch this list in the controller to filter by username.